# How do I use the SUM Function in Oracle SQL to produce the below output?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an SQL Programming question based on Sum Function.Supposing, I have the following table.

```
       ID   Values 

        1     20
        1     30
        1     100
        2     10
        2     1
        2     12
        3     45
        3     66
```

How do I calculate the sum of the values pertaining to an ID and add it to a new column. I also would like to group it by ID. For Example:

```
           ID  Values  Total_Value

            1    20       150
            1    30       150
            1    100      150
            2    10       23
            2    1        23 
            2    12       23
            3    45       111
            3    66       111
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Please adjust yours tags as `MySQL`  and `Oracle RDBMS` are different products.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this can easily be done using a window function:

```
select id, 
       value,
       sum(value) over (partition by id) as total_value_for_id
from the_table
order by id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use analytic functions.  That is what they are there for:

```
select id, value, sum(value) over (partition by id) as totalvalue
from table t
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I get from your question, sum is equal to sum of values for those rows with same id. For all rows with Id 1 sum is 150, and for 2 it is 23.

So you will need sub query that will sum Values by Id, and after that you can Join those two tables by Id.

```
Select table.*, sumtable.Sum
From table
Join (Select Sum(Values) As Sum, ID From table Group By ID) sumtable 
       On table.ID = sumtable.ID
```

Comment: ...and you don't need `LEFT JOIN`, as there will always be matching rows.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: you don't need a join to begin with.

Comment: But, not all databases support `OVER`.

Comment: But Oracle does. And there are less DBMS *not* supporting window functions than those supporting them

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this either by an inner select (where you will calculate sum) or by creating a function and use it on your select statement. Function must accept an ID as parameter and return the SUM.

Comment: None of that is necessary